# Is there any hack to close the current tab in an Angular yet with a button clicked?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a method `onExit()` and trying to **close** the browser's current **tab/exit** from the application. I have tried with this code component.ts

```
onExit() {
    console.log("closing the web!");

    window.close();
  }
```

and compoent.html

```
<button type="button" id="F1" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onExit()">Exit (F1)</button>
```

But getting the console warning says ***"Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."***

**If anyone knows the solution would be great.**

Thanks.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was a way to do this, that seems like a big security vulnerability.

Comment: As the error says, a script can only close a tab or window if it opened that tab or window. If your app opens some kind of child window then you’d be able to close it from the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JohnMontgomery

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible due to security reasons.

Comment: SP, thanks for your straight forward answer. I'm wondering many people suggesting the use window.open('', '_self', '') window.close() on the internet that doesn't work then why they are not alert?

Comment: if the window was opened by a script with `window.open` then, it can be closed by the same script with `window.close`. read the error. it says `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.`